# SoundCloud API: how to use SoundCloud song w/o the embed player?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, embed, soundcloud

According to the **[SoundCloud API Guide](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide)**, I can play sounds from SoundCloud on a web page or web application, *without* using the embedded player (example code below):

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/136405212&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

I want to try and play SoundCloud assets without this embed; instead, I want to find out how to:

- use an **HTML5 audio player** to play the song
- play a song ***without* any audio players** (i.e. "play this song `onLoad`")

Any help with this, including anything that can use JavaScript and/or jQuery, will be much appreciated.

### Original text:

> Yep, you can also play sounds from your application. Depending on your needs, you can embed a player widget, use the JavaScript SDK to stream audio content in the browser, or feed a stream url into your own audio player. You can also use our Widget API to control the player and handle events. *(from* http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing*)*

### Examples:

- Attempt on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/PbhCC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try SoundCloud's [JavaScript API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) for streaming tracks and other stuff.

Comment: Pasted the API source into the sidebar instead (doesn't work by putting it in the HTML window). Finally got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/PbhCC/

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on @Marco's answer:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    stream = new Audio(),
    client_id = '?client_id=d4ab52d80ed2e7790c3a243495b30093';
xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/136405212.json' + client_id);
xhr.onload = function(){
  var track = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  stream.src = track.stream_url + client_id;
  stream.play();
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: @017Bluefield in your javascript console or any place you can execute javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But should I paste the code as is (global), or inside of a function (local)?

Comment: This is really what I wanted. I don't know why `SC.stream()` does not work after copy pasting also. Thanks @idbehold